# Arabic language displayed not properly in iOS Phonegap App

Tags: ios, cordova, localization, arabic

I have an issue with the Arabic font in an Phonegap App. It isnt displayed correctly so I am getting some strange letters back if i view it in the phonegap app.

[image: Strange letters]

can anyone tell me why I get such a string and how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your html page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link [**ARABIC FONTS ON IOS**](http://blog.gabemastey.com/post/42979676803/arabic-fonts-on-ios-android-webkit-for-phonegap-app) for customizing the font,

**@font-face** did not work with custom arabic fonts on Android & iOS webkit versions. If you have any clarification,let me know,Thanks,..

Comment: the app is getting the Arabic string from a Server and display the String correctly in the mobile safari browser. When I view the String in the app I get the String in the screenshot

Comment: myself also got problem in adding the local language font-face,But i got the correct zip file for the font-face which we need to add it in the phonegap ,so try like this..

Comment: well I found out that this behaviour does not caused by phonegap/cordova or iOS. Its also messed up when I open the page in the desktop browser. So it looks like an encoding problem from the page itself.

Comment: @oneandonlycore : ok verify it,Also if you add the font-face as ttf format,so you can access your neeeded font in phonegap..

Answer (score -4):

It is the real answer

For

I have an issue with the Arabic font in an Phonegap App. It isnt displayed correctly so I am getting some strange letters back if i view it in the phonegap app.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```